# Queue macro by changing Cell.Font.Bold

Tags: excel, vba

I know there is an option to queue a macro by clicking into a cell. (Worksheet_SelectionChange)
But is there also an option where the macro gets queued if I change the cell font boldness?

I always want to start the macro when I change a cell to "bold".

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might program your custom event for that specific case. A more simple approach can be to check if determined cell o cell in a determined range is put to bold and the call the macro.
Find a example where the msg is thrown when a bold cell is found in the range "A1:C10". It is triggered on selection change (so when pressing enter after setting the cell to bold).
You would need to call the macro you want where the message is thrown.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
        ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")
    
    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
               Is Nothing Then
    
    ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
            ' changed.
            ' Place your code here.
            MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
            For Each cell In KeyCells
                If cell.Font.Bold = True Then
                    MsgBox ("a cell is bold!")
                End If
            Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer
That is how I do it at the moment. The reason for this question is, that most users change the font within a cell with a key combination (ctrl + b) and then they don’t press enter. That’s why I got a lot of complains and wanted to change that.

Comment: You are welcome. Sure its much more direct if the method was triggered from keyboard shortcut, or the turn to bold itself. However you can check that customizing that event to trigger your method, would involve checking classes and events in VBA and develop that yourself, which would is not immediate if you are not into VBA programming. Give it a try, that should be a nice challenge!. You can accept the answer if you think that resolves your problem. ;)